# Solr repeater/slave not working

Tags: lucene, solr

i have a solr repeater set up, that appears to be working correctly as a slave, and i thought i had the master part set right as well:

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler">
<lst name="master">
  <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
  <str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>

  <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,stopwords.txt,synonyms.txt</str>
</lst>
<lst name="slave">
  <str name="masterUrl">http://HOST:PORT/solr/replication</str>
  <str name="pollInterval">00:00:00</str>
</lst>
```

on my repeaters slave i have:

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
<lst name="slave">

    <!--fully qualified url for the replication handler of master . It is possible to pass on this as a request param for the fetchindex command-->
    <str name="masterUrl">http://REPEATER:8080/solr/replication</str>

    <!--Interval in which the slave should poll master .Format is HH:mm:ss . If this is absent slave does not poll automatically.
     But a fetchindex can be triggered from the admin or the http API -->
    <str name="pollInterval">00:00:00</str>
    <!-- THE FOLLOWING PARAMETERS ARE USUALLY NOT REQUIRED-->
    <!--to use compression while transferring the index files. The possible values are internal|external
     if the value is 'external' make sure that your master Solr has the settings to honour the accept-encoding header.
     see here for details http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrHttpCompression
     If it is 'internal' everything will be taken care of automatically.
     USE THIS ONLY IF YOUR BANDWIDTH IS LOW . THIS CAN ACTUALLY SLOWDOWN REPLICATION IN A LAN-->
    <str name="compression">internal</str>
    <!--The following values are used when the slave connects to the master to download the index files.
     Default values implicitly set as 5000ms and 10000ms respectively. The user DOES NOT need to specify
     these unless the bandwidth is extremely low or if there is an extremely high latency-->
    <str name="httpConnTimeout">5000</str>
    <str name="httpReadTimeout">10000</str>

    <!-- If HTTP Basic authentication is enabled on the master, then the slave can be configured with the following
    <str name="httpBasicAuthUser">username</str>
    <str name="httpBasicAuthPassword">password</str>
```

-->

however, the repeater seemsto work as an ok slave, but when i send a replication command to the repeater's slave, it says ok, no errors in the log, but when i check the replication status i get:

'{ "responseHeader":{ "status":0, "QTime":47}, "details":{ "indexSize":"52 bytes", "indexPath":"/index/solr/solr.141.megaindex.prod/data/index", "commits":[], "isMaster":"false", "isSlave":"true", "indexVersion":1290200498685, "generation":1, "slave":{ "masterDetails":{ "indexSize":"20.61 GB", "indexPath":"/journals7/solr/solr.141.cow.prod/data/index", "commits":[], "isMaster":"true", "isSlave":"true", "indexVersion":1288551085602, "generation":27}, "masterUrl":"http://REPEATER.org:8080/solr.141.cow.prod/replication", "pollInterval":"00:00:00", "indexReplicatedAt":"Fri Nov 19 16:21:21 EST 2010", "indexReplicatedAtList":["Fri Nov 19 16:21:21 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 16:16:30 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 16:15:05 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 16:12:28 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 16:11:19 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 16:01:45 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 15:57:38 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 15:54:25 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 15:50:06 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 15:49:25 EST 2010"], "replicationFailedAtList":["Fri Nov 19 16:21:21 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 16:16:30 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 16:15:05 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 16:12:28 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 16:11:19 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 16:01:45 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 15:57:38 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 15:54:25 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 15:50:06 EST 2010", "Fri Nov 19 15:49:25 EST 2010"], "timesIndexReplicated":"17", "lastCycleBytesDownloaded":"0", "timesFailed":"17", "replicationFailedAt":"Fri Nov 19 16:21:21 EST 2010", "previousCycleTimeInSeconds":"0", "isPollingDisabled":"false", "isReplicating":"false"}}, "WARNING":"This response format is experimental. It is likely to change in the future."}';

the commits part is always empty, on the functional repeater, after its been told to replicate, there is a file list.  neither the repeater nor the slave are indicating whats going on.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You have the poll interval set to 0. Try something higher - I'm not sure how functional Solr is on a zero-based poll.